# How to use company-arguments while updating stripe connect account

Tags: c#, nuget, stripe-payments, nuget-package

We are upgrading account requests API version to **2020-03-02** from 2018-02-06

So as part of Accounts API Argument [Changes](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/required-updates/accounts-arguments#company-arguments) we are changing the parameters

So while creating or updating **company** connect account few of the arguments are managed by persons object and there are other arguments to use other which are not part of persons object

[image]

I have written something like this
[image]

[image]
so how to hit stripe with **personcreateoptions** which is used to manage persons object and **accountupdateoptions** which is used for other arguments?

**--We are using 20.3.0 Stripe.Net NuGet Package**

Answer (score 0):

The version 20.3.0 of stripe-dotnet was released on [2018-10-31](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2030---2018-10-31). At that time, the library was pinned to the most recent API version [2018-09-24](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2018-09-24). All API requests the library makes will always use that specific API version and it is impossible for you to make a different call with different arguments.

This means that if you stay on that version of stripe-dotnet, you can not make any of the changes you outlined in your question. All the calls you make will use the old API version and the old shape of the account. This means that to send those parameters, you would never use the Persons API and do everything through Account and its `LegalEntity`.

If you want to move to a more recent API version, you will have to upgrade stripe-dotnet to a more recent version that matches that API version. This likely means migrating to the most recent version of stripe-dotnet and going through some of the renames and breaking changes due to all the API versions changes since you built your integration.

Upgrading is not a requirement for those changes though. You can pass all relevant parameters through the old API the way you have always been doing this. So if you can't upgrade you can still do this by using `LegalEntity`.